# How to negate tmpwatch exclude-pattern

Tags: wildcards

I want to negate `--exclude-pattern` option so that tmpwatch excludes all but files matching the pattern.

For exemple , if I want to remove only `*.gz` files it would be something like that :

```
 tmpwatch 10d --exclude-pattern=!*.gz .
```

I appreciate your help as tmpwatch manpage isn't really helpful.

> -X, --exclude-pattern=pattern
>   Skip paths matching pattern; if a directory matches pattern, all files contained in it are skipped too. pattern must match an absolute path that contains no symbolic links.